Target class [teacher] does not exist. LARAVEL 11.10.0
I'm working on a Laravel application where I need to protect certain routes based on user roles. I have created two middlewares: one for the "teacher" role and another for the "student" role. The student middleware works as expected, but I'm having issues with the teacher middleware.
Here is my setup:
Middleware: CheckTeacherRole
I created the middleware using the Artisan command and added the following code:
Middlewares:
TeacherMiddleware
<?php

// app/Http/Middleware/TeacherMiddleware.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class TeacherMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isTeacher()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->route('index')->with('error', 'Unauthorized access');
    }

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'teacher' => \App\Http\Middleware\TeacherMiddleware::class,
    ];
}


StudentMiddleware:
<?php

// app/Http/Middleware/TeacherMiddleware.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StudentMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isStudent()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->route('index')->with('error', 'Unauthorized access');
    }

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'student' => \App\Http\Middleware\StudentMiddleware::class,
    ];
}


routes<web:
Route::middleware('student')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/student/projects', [ProjectController::class, 'studentProjects'])->name('student.projects');
    Route::get('/student/projects/pdf', [ProjectController::class, 'generatePDFStudent'])->name('student.projects.pdf');
});

Route::middleware('teacher')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/teacher/projects', [ProjectController::class, 'teacherProjects'])->name('teacher.projects');
    Route::get('/teacher/projects/create', [ProjectController::class, 'create'])->name('projects.create');
});

bootstrap<app:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;


return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
        $middleware->alias(['teacher' => \App\Http\Middleware\TeacherMiddleware::class]);
        $middleware->alias(['student' => \App\Http\Middleware\StudentMiddleware::class]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();


The error:

When I add the routes without the teacher middleware, it works. Also student middleware works always
The model User class:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    const ROLE_STUDENT = 'student';
    const ROLE_TEACHER = 'teacher';

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'phone', 'rol', 'password', 'email'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $dates = ['email_verified_at'];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_user')
            ->withPivot('start_date')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function teacherProjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class, 'teacher_id');
    }


    public function isStudent()
    {
        return $this->rol === self::ROLE_STUDENT;
    }

    public function isTeacher()
    {
        return $this->rol === self::ROLE_TEACHER;
    }
}


And the previous method that is called is when i click to verify in login:
    public function login(Request $request) {

        //more code...

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $user = Auth::user();

            if ($user->isStudent()) {
                return redirect()->route('student.projects')->withSuccess('Signed in');
            } elseif ($user->isTeacher()) {
                return redirect()->route('teacher.projects')->withSuccess('Signed in');
            }

        }

        return redirect("login")->withErrors(['email' => 'Email address or password is incorrect.'])->withInput();
    }


Can you add the methods "isTeacher()" and "isStudent()" to your question ? also provide more backtrace of the error (the line of the error and previous files that were called)

What does "I'm having issues" mean? Also what do you think the $routeMiddleware property is doing? (Hint: it's not doing anything.)

What you are getting when you are accessing routes having teacher middleware?? Specify what issue you are facing??

@N69S i have an attribute rol in User class, so i have to limitate eache user routes. this is the User model:
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasFactory, Notifiable;
const ROLE_STUDENT = 'student';
const ROLE_TEACHER = 'teacher';
protected $table = 'users';

//more methods...
public function isStudent()
{
return $this->rol === self::ROLE_STUDENT;
}
public function isTeacher()
{
return $this->rol === self::ROLE_TEACHER;
}
}
also, the last file that is called is UserController that i would write all in the post

Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Blade? You haven't shared any such code. Also, can you share the full and exact error message?

@NicoHaase yeah, when i try to access into /teacer/projects after loggin with a role teacher acount it gives me the next error:
Internal Server Error
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [teacher] does not exist.
When i write the middlewares teacher routes in auth middleware it works

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, what makes you think the error is related to Blade?

@NicoHaase its all added in my question

@ArlequinaCFClubdefutbol your error is related to a BindingResolutionException which mean that you have a route in the format of /path/{teacher} and in your controller method you have function whaterver(Teacher $teacher). The error is related to that Teacher class not being found. nothing to do with middleware. maybe you meant to do  function whaterver(User $teacher). to give you the exact solution, you need to add the controller method that is throwing the error to your question as well as the namespace and use part (top part) of the controller.

@N69S i dont have a Teacher class, i just have an user (with rol attribute) class and a project class
